# Kogito Custom property panel for BPMN editor

Tags: editor, bpmn, kogito

I'm using kogito standalone bpmn editor in a web app. I want to override the property panel of the editor with my own property panel. I tried decoding the index.js but it doesn't work

Hi, I'm using kogito standalone bpmn editor in a web app. I want to override the property panel of the editor with my own property panel. I tried decoding the index.js but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The BPMN Editor code lives here https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/tree/main/packages/stunner-editors/kie-wb-common-stunner/kie-wb-common-stunner-sets/kie-wb-common-stunner-bpmn. It's a GWT application. [Here](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/tree/main/packages/stunner-editors/kie-wb-common-stunner/kie-wb-common-stunner-sets/kie-wb-common-stunner-bpmn/kie-wb-common-stunner-bpmn-kogito-runtime#running-in-sdm), you can learn you to run the application in dev mode in your local machine, facilitating your experiments.